# Django absolute __in query

Tags: django

I have a list of UUIDs that represent users in a DB table. I want to fetch all the users that match this criteria so I use the `__in` filter:

```
users = User.objects.filter(user__in=uuids)
```

I would like to raise an exception if not all of the UUIDs appear in the table. In other words, I expect to get a result back for each uuid such that `len(users) == len(uuids)`. Is there an easy Django way to do it? If not, is there an easy way for me to create this behavior?

Comment: Why not perform this check (with for example `assert len(users) == len(uuids)`?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem - That's what I'm doing, but I'd prefer to have the code look a bit more elegant as this repeats itself so many times.

Answer (score 0):

You could use exclude if you like it gives you the objects that does not match the query

```
#this returns true if one or more and dont need to use len()
#if it looks better for you you can try it out
#if everything is fine will return None
if User.objects.filter().exclude(user__in=uiids).first(): 
   raise your_error
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't think too complicated. You want to know if a list of something is fully contained in another list of something, that's just plain python:

```
user_ids = User.objects.values_list('user_id',flat=True)
if not set(uuids).issubset(user_ids): # or use .difference() to get the uuids missing from user_ids
    raise stuff
```